# When converting a program from x86 to x64 platform, the linker command line is still x86, resulting in a program error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, platform

When I finished platform replacement from x86 to x64 in vs2019, the VC++ Directories-General changed to x64 correctly, as shown in the following figure
[image]

But the Linker-Command Line doesn't change，and the Content is still x86,as shown in the following figure
[image]

So the program has an error，as shown in the following figure
[image]

therefore I want to ask how to change the linker command to x64, when the platform converting a program from x86 to x64.

Picture from a new project，like this.

[image]

thank you very very so much ,Warm hearted people

**thank all big guys' suggestion**

so I find the Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies,
and go into Macros to find like E:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\msvc2017_x64\lib,
and my QT installation directory contains msvc2017_x64 directory .
but I see all options is not about msvc2017_x64,and all is msvc2017,
as shown in the following picture.
[image]

**So how can I linker my msvc2017_x64 when it isn't in Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies/Macros.**

thank you answer very very very so much

Comment: You need to go to Linker/Input and replace the x86 libraries with their x64 equivalents

Comment: Where in the command line for the linker is there an error?

Comment: Changing the setting from Win32 to x64 will not replace any of your 3rd party binaries with x64 compiled binaries compiled with your compiler.  You need to obtain 64 bit binaries for all of the libraries you are using and switch your linker settings to use the 64 bit versions.

Comment: sorry big guys, i am first to use stackoverfloew ask question

Comment: @GReyQT Linker/Input not Linker/System, Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies will contain the names of the libraries you are linking with.

Comment: @johnI followed your advice, but I had a new problem that I couldn't solve.And I updated the details of the problem

Comment: @drescherjm i followed your advice, but I had a new problem that I couldn't solve.And I updated the details of the problem